# Why when i did a search for ExpiryDat eq '2023-05-07', i got items with those ExpiryDate 2023-05-06T23:00:00Z

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, online

I have a custom list with field of type DateOnly named ExpiryDate:-

[image]

and when i did this API call to get items with Expiry date = `ExpiryDat eq '2023-05-07'` >> I got items with this ExpiryDate `2023-05-06T23:00:00Z`.. any advice? so why i am searching for `7 May 2023` and i am getting items with expirtydate = `6 May 2023`

Here is the site regional settings:-

[image]

Comment: Please add the API call/code to your question

Comment: @Callum Crowley `https://****.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListData')/items?$filter=ExpiryDate eq '2023-05-07'`

Comment: @microsoftdeveloperdesigner, read this article, it might help you: [How Date-Time Columns Work In SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-date-time-columns-works-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: @GaneshSanap so users will get different results on the API if they have different time zones? similar to how the UI works?

Answer (score 0):

Its because SharePoint stores dates in UTC time. I guess your timezone or the sitecollection time zone is GMT +1.

When you save a Date as 2023-05-07, what is really being stored is 23-05-06T23:00:00Z. When SharePoint shows you the value on its interface, it takes this timezone into account and shows you the value with that 1hour difference, thats why you don't notice.

So if you want to get all dates on 2023-05-07T00:00:00Z, what you really need to query is the date with 1 hour less -> 2023-05-06T23:00:00Z

Comment: so does this depend on the user profile regional setting or on the site collection regional setting ?

Comment: Sitecollection regional setting